# Usos das notações @Bean e @Autowired e para que servem?

Tags: spring

Tenho dificuldade em compreender essas duas notações e para que servem.
Li documentação e algumas respostas sobre, e pelo que entendi o @Bean seria uma criação de instância de uma classe, e o @Autowired usaria essa instância. Seria isso? Poderia comparar essas notações com o uso do padrão Singleton?
Teria algum exemplo de situação que eu teria que usa-las?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Component`, `@Service` e @`Repository` são usados quando você quer que seus beans sejam auto configurados pelo spring.

`@Bean` é usado quando você precisa explicitamente configurar o bean ao invés de deixar o spring automaticamente fazer. Por exemplo, para configuração de DataSource:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSource ds = null;
        try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/seuLockUp");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Por padrão, os beans no spring são singletons, ou seja, uma instância por container context.

`@autowired` é como você injeta, ou seja, usa seus beans pelo projeto.

Comment: Um link para a documentação ajuda. Creio que você consiga encontrar um link para algum tutorial da Baeldung que abarque de modo geral essas anotações